# Injunction relief without posting bond

Tags: contract-law

Can you explain in simple english the meaning of this sentence? Context is transfer of proprietary data.

> the Receiving Party agrees that the Disclosing Party may be entitled, without proof of special damages, to  seek the remedies of injunction relief without posting bond, as well as specific performance and other equitable relief.

In particular I don't know what "without posting bond" means. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In court, parties typically seek relief in the form of money -- for breaching a contract, for selling a defective product, for causing personal injuries.

In other cases, though, a party asks for injunctive relief: an order that the other party start or stop doing something. For instance, if you and Donald Trump entered into a nondisclosure agreement, and then you announced plans to sell the Pee Tape you made with him, he might ask for an injunction ordering you to honor the nondisclosure agreement.

It would take some time for a court to hear and decide the entire case, so Trump would probably also ask for a "preliminary injunction" to stop you from selling the video while the case is moving forward. Under certain circumstances, the court may be willing to allow that.

But the court will also recognize that this involves some risk to you as the author. It's Christmastime, so preventing you from selling your video now means you're probably going to miss out on a lot of money that the court might eventually decide you were entitled to all along.

To protect against that, the court may make some estimate of the potential loss you would suffer and force Trump to post a bond equal to that amount before the court will grant the injunction. If Trump wins and you are barred from selling the Pee Tape, Trump gets his money back. If Trump loses and you are permitted to sell the Pee Tape, the court will probably order the bond to be released to you to compensate for your lost sales.

In the language you're citing, then, the parties are purporting to agree that one is entitled to injunctive relief without posting bond.

Answer (score 0):

,It is not uncommon for a court to require one (or both) of the parties to pay money into the court to cover the costs/damages of the other party, usually at the request of that other party. This clause specifically prevents the “Disclosing Party” from requesting such a bond for injunctive relief.